# SQL filtered index when the column in the filtered expression is possible not present?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I want to create a SQL command to create an index with condition.
Both columns on which the index is based as well as the column used in the filter expression are possible not present.
So I added a condition that both columns are present but I still get an *Invalid Column Name* error for the column in the filter expression.
Is there a way around this?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
       FROM sys.all_columns 
       WHERE name='Field1' 
       AND object_id=OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Table1]') )
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
       FROM sys.all_columns 
       WHERE name='Field2' 
       AND object_id=OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Table1]') )

BEGIN

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table1_Field1] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [Field1]
) 
WHERE ([Field2]=(1))

END
```

Table for which the problem occurs

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
     [Field1] [int] 
)
```

Comment: Your code should [works without any error/exception](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/798a2/1)!! ;).

Comment: @shA.t I get an Invalid Column Name error.
When I leave `WHERE ([Field2]=(1))` out ik works without error.

Comment: @shA.t In your example the Field2 is present in Table1, the poblem occurs when Field2 is not present

Comment: So why do you check its existence of table1? =>  `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.all_columns WHERE name='Field2' AND object_id=OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Table1]')`

Comment: can you provide table schema for us to test

Comment: @shA.t I check for the existance of field1 and field2 in table1 because if both exist then I want to add the index otherwise I want to do nothing. In the latter case I get the error about Field2 although the Create Index command isn't executed

Comment: @TheGameiswar I have edited the question with the table schema

Comment: You're getting a *compile* error - your code doesn't get as far as *running* to perform the runtime checks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I get that. I was looking for a way around that. I use dynamic SQL now as in shA.t's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you really want, I think you need to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(max) = N'Table2', @field1 nvarchar(max) = N'Field1', @field2 nvarchar(max) = N'Field2';
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

if exists (select 1 
       from sys.all_columns
       where name = @field1
       and [object_id] = object_id(@tableName))
and exists (select 1 
       from sys.all_columns
       where name = @field2
       and [object_id] = object_id(@tableName))
begin
    set @sql = 'create nonclustered index [IX_'+@tableName+'_'+@field1+'] on [dbo].['+@tableName+'] ( ['+@field1+']) where ['+@field2+']= 1';
end
else if exists (select 1 
       from sys.all_columns
       where name = @field1
       and [object_id] = object_id(@tableName))
begin
    set @sql = 'create nonclustered index [IX_'+@tableName+'_'+@field1+'] on [dbo].['+@tableName+'] ( ['+@field1+'])';
end
else if exists (select 1 
       from sys.all_columns
       where name = @field2
       and [object_id] = object_id(@tableName))
begin
    set @sql = 'create nonclustered index [IX_'+@tableName+'_'+@field2+'] on [dbo].['+@tableName+'] ( ['+@field2+'])';
end

exec sp_sqlexec @sql;
go
```